# Computing the discrete-time difference equation when the system matrix is non-invertible

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, matrix-equations

If we have a continuous time equation,

$$ \dot{x}(t) = A x(t) + B u(t)$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times1}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, u \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$, the analytical solution is obtained as

$$x(t) = e^{A t} x(0) + \int_0^t e^{A(t-\tau)}B u(\tau)\, d\tau$$

Converting this to discrete-time, with sample-time $T_s$, and assuming that all eigen-values of $A$ are real & distinct and $u$ remains constant within each sample interval, $k$ to $k+1$, we get the following **difference** equation,

$$x[k+1] = e^{A T_s} x[k] + \left[\int_0^t e^{A\tau}B \, d\tau\right] u[k]$$

Which can be written as

$$x[k+1] = A_d  x[k] + B_d u[k]$$

When the original matrix $A$ is invertible, the integral term corresponding to $B_d$ can be written as

$$B_d = A^{-1}(A_d - I)$$

The question is, **What about the case when A is non-invertible**?  In particular, if my $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \end{bmatrix}$. How do I obtain the corresponding $B_d$?